# tlmgr with Ubuntu TexLive

Tags: installing

I installed `TexLive` through Software Center of Ubuntu.
However it does not contain tlmgr which is quite useful to update the packages.

Is it possible to use `tlmgr` with default `TexLive`?
If yes, how can I only install tlmgr (without installing `TexLive 2011`)? I ran `install.pl` script in the downloadable `TexLive 2011` installer folder, but I could not find a way to install only `tlmgr`.

Thanks.

Comment: No.  Debian/Ubuntu's version of TeX Live will always be behind the most current version, and cannot be made to work with `tlmgr` (and probably never will).

Comment: Of course, many packages are available as a `.tds.zip` file, which are a breeze to install even on a default Debian/etc. installation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use both `tlmgr` and `apt-get` (Ubuntu's package manager). Either you manually install TeXLive 2011 from [texlive](http://www.texlive.org) and use `tlmgr` (which I would recommend), or you go with Ubuntu's packaged version of TeXLive (outdated, based on TeXLive 2009) and update it through `apt-get`, but you can't mix both.

If you go for a manual install of the latest TeXLive, consider using `equivs` to create a dummy TeXLive debian package and have your custom TeXLive installation taken into account for Ubuntu dependencies. Practically, put the following into a file called `texlive-local.equivs`:

```
Section: misc
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: texlive-local
Version: 2011-1~1
Maintainer: you <you@domain.org>
Provides: biblatex, biblatex-dw, cm-super, cm-super-minimal, context, dvipng, feynmf, fragmaster, lacheck, latex-beamer, latex-cjk-all, latex-cjk-chinese, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bkai00mp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-bsmi00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gbsn00lp, latex-cjk-chinese-arphic-gkai00mp, latex-cjk-common, latex-cjk-japanese, latex-cjk-japanese-wadalab, latex-cjk-korean, latex-cjk-thai, latex-cjk-xcjk, latexmk, latex-sanskrit, latex-xcolor, lcdf-typetools, lmodern, luatex, musixlyr, musixtex, pgf, preview-latex-style, prosper, ps2eps, psutils, purifyeps, t1utils, tex4ht, tex4ht-common, tex-gyre, texlive, texlive-base, texlive-bibtex-extra, texlive-binaries, texlive-common, texlive-doc-base, texlive-doc-bg, texlive-doc-cs+sk, texlive-doc-de, texlive-doc-el, texlive-doc-en, texlive-doc-es, texlive-doc-fi, texlive-doc-fr, texlive-doc-it, texlive-doc-ja, texlive-doc-ko, texlive-doc-mn, texlive-doc-nl, texlive-doc-pl, texlive-doc-pt, texlive-doc-ru, texlive-doc-si, texlive-doc-th, texlive-doc-tr, texlive-doc-uk, texlive-doc-vi, texlive-doc-zh, texlive-extra-utils, texlive-fonts-extra, texlive-fonts-extra-doc, texlive-fonts-recommended, texlive-fonts-recommended-doc, texlive-font-utils, texlive-formats-extra, texlive-games, texlive-generic-extra, texlive-generic-recommended, texlive-humanities, texlive-humanities-doc, texlive-lang-african, texlive-lang-all, texlive-lang-arab, texlive-lang-arabic, texlive-lang-armenian, texlive-lang-croatian, texlive-lang-cyrillic, texlive-lang-czechslovak, texlive-lang-danish, texlive-lang-dutch, texlive-lang-finnish, texlive-lang-french, texlive-lang-german, texlive-lang-greek, texlive-lang-hebrew, texlive-lang-hungarian, texlive-lang-indic, texlive-lang-italian, texlive-lang-latin, texlive-lang-latvian, texlive-lang-lithuanian, texlive-lang-manju, texlive-lang-mongolian, texlive-lang-norwegian, texlive-lang-other, texlive-lang-polish, texlive-lang-portuguese, texlive-lang-spanish, texlive-lang-swedish, texlive-lang-tibetan, texlive-lang-ukenglish, texlive-lang-vietnamese, texlive-latex3, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-base-doc, texlive-latex-extra, texlive-latex-extra-doc, texlive-latex-recommended, texlive-latex-recommended-doc, texlive-luatex, texlive-math-extra, texlive-metapost, texlive-metapost-doc, texlive-music, texlive-omega, texlive-pictures, texlive-pictures-doc, texlive-plain-extra, texlive-pstricks, texlive-pstricks-doc, texlive-publishers, texlive-publishers-doc, texlive-science, texlive-science-doc, texlive-xetex, texpower, texpower-manual, thailatex, tipa, ttf-freefont, ttf-gfs-artemisia, ttf-gfs-baskerville, ttf-gfs-bodoni-classic, ttf-gfs-didot, ttf-gfs-didot-classic, ttf-gfs-gazis, ttf-gfs-neohellenic, ttf-gfs-olga, ttf-gfs-porson, ttf-gfs-solomos, ttf-gfs-theokritos, ttf-sil-gentium, xindy, xindy-rules
Architecture: all
Description: My local installation of TeX Live 2011.
 A full "vanilla" TeX Live 2011
 http://tug.org/texlive/debian#vanilla
```

and run

```
sudo apt-get install equivs
equivs-control texlive-local
equivs-build texlive-local.equivs
sudo dpkg -i texlive-local_2011-1~1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for above answer. Will above procedure allow me to install 'bare-minimum' TexLive 2011 packages (just like the default Ubuntu Software Center version)? If yes, how do I specify that?

I am not a heavy user of LaTex and do not have so much of disk space as to allow full installation of LaTex 2011.

Comment: The TeXLive installer let you choose which "scheme" you want to install, which is basically a pre-determined selection of packages (see [the installation documentation on www.tug.org](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-26023r5) for the list of schemes). Given your limited disk space, start with the "basic" scheme and simply manually add the extra packages you need with `tlmgr`.

Comment: I installed the basic version of TexLive 2011, but tlmgr seems to be missing. How do I install tlmgr only while retaining basic version of TexLive 2011? I get `tlmgr: command not found` when I run command `tlmgr`.

Comment: Did you add TeX Live to your path?