# texlive-latex-extra and koma-moderncvclassic

Tags: texlive, koma-script, ubuntu, moderncv

I installed the ubuntu package texlive-latex-extra which contains a latex package "koma-moderncvclassic".

However, if I compile a document

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[myblue]{koma-moderncvclassic}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

pdflatex will not find it

```
! LaTeX Error: File `koma-moderncvclassic.sty' not found.
```

Comment: Please don't use Ubuntu's version of TeX Live, it's TL 2009 and heavily outdated. See [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) for a proper install. Just don't mind the extra 2GB of space and keep the Ubuntu packages to satisfy the (IMHO artificial) dependencies. Note that TL 2012 just came out this weekend!

Comment: Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) has TeXLive 2012

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There is a document class called `moderncv` which is used by calling `\documentclass{moderncv}`. Is this what you want?

Comment: Last time i installed vanilla Texlive I ran into trouble when I updated Ubuntu. If indeed 12.10 will finally have an updated Texlive pack ill just wit till oktober.
@Seamus I took a template that was set up like that... maybe that was outdated too. thanks anyways.

Comment: I simply downloaded the whole package from ctan and used the template from the package, so it works for now.

Comment: @MartinScharrer No need to keep the Ubuntu TeXLive packages to satisfy TeX dependencies; you can instead use `equivs` to tell the Ubuntu / Debian package manager to consider certain dependencies as fulfilled. See the paragraph on TUG about [Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla) or [my answer to a similar question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56005/tlmgr-with-ubuntu-texlive/56010#56010) here on StackExchange.

Comment: @Xavier: I know about this, but it didn't fully work for me and wasn't trivial, too. I just mentioned the simplest way to do it, so that it can also be done by beginners.

Comment: @Herbert: A TeX Live 2012 which will never be updated ... :-( Or will it now include `tlmgr`?